# Getting what appears to be a PHP4 error on my PHP5 server

Tags: php

I'm getting the below error on my server:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /nfs/c03/h03/mnt/53496/domains/chuggington.com/deploy/releases/20100908062138/system/application/models/home_model.php on line 5
```

However, the code works in a different part of the server (the development side). This is me trying to put it live.

Below is the code it is referring to:

```
<?php

class Home_model extends Model {

    public function Home_model()
    {
        // model constructor
        parent::Model();
    }

    function getCode(){
        $ip_address = 'INET_ATON('.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].')';
        //echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $this->db->select('country');
        $this->db->order_by('ip', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('ip2nation', array('ip <'=>$ip_address), '0,1');
        //print_r($query->row('country'));
        return $query->row('country');
    }
}
?>
```

Can syslink cause this sort of error? There are no htaccess scripts interfering either.

Thanks

---EDIT---

I have run a phpinfo on the site and it's running php 5.2.6. I'll try the addhandler change and see if that works.

Just tried the addhandler and  i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the server is running PHP 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some hosts may offer both PHP4 and PHP5 environments and require you to choose one or the other, defaulting to PHP4. Our host requires a `AddHandler php5-script .php` line in the .htaccess file of directories that should use PHP5. Others may offer a switch in a control panel.

Consult your [host's manual](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1701/Why+does+my+site+revert+back+to+PHP+4%3F+).

Comment: There are still hosts that default to PHP4? Can you give an example so that i never accidently get a domain there? I mean being backwards compatible is fine and good, but thats like... well, defaulting to Win98 servers. Default should be at least a little up-to-date with option to use the old version, not the other way around.

Comment: @dbemerlin I agree, but it's not uncommon. No personal experience: [MediaTemple](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1701/Why+does+my+site+revert+back+to+PHP+4%3F+) Personal experience: [Heteml](http://heteml.jp/support/manual/php5/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove "public". And put a phpinfo(); on top of that file. Find out what's wrong.

There's probably an alternative PHP4 interpreter installed, and whatever script accesses your class runs in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other code in the same file? This error seems to me like another class or function hasn't been closed properly with a bracket } above. Or something of the kind.