# Parse Error: Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER Error: Unexpected ',' while expecting '('

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth

Using PHP GMail OAuth Library/Sample.

```
$options = array(
    'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER,
    'version' => '1.0',
    'consumerKey' => $THREE_LEGGED_CONSUMER_KEY,
    'callbackUrl' => getCurrentUrl(),
    'requestTokenUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken',
    'userAuthorizationUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken',
    'accessTokenUrl' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken'
);
```

Here's the error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '(' 
This is from line 77:  the 'requestScheme' => Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER, line, any ideas?

**Edit:  I'm using PHP 4.4.8**

Comment: What's your PHP version? (If you're not sure, `echo phpversion();` and see.)

Comment: No ideas - using this library and I can't find a specification.

Comment: Seems very related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665156/getting-what-appears-to-be-a-php4-error-on-my-php5-server

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/source/browse/#svn/trunk/php

Comment: Thanks deceze, didn't find anything when I searched before, checking it out now

Comment: Just checked - I'm using version 4.4.8What's the assumption? My server is using php 4 and I need to switch it to php5?

Comment: Yes indeed. The syntax is legal in PHP5, but AFAIA not legal in PHP4. The only explanation why you'd get this error would be that you're running on PHP4.

Comment: So I need to change this in my server settings with my host, correct?

Comment: @Bob: have you read our answers yet?

Comment: Yes, you guys were right, looks like it was the 4.8.8 - once I switched to 5, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using PHP 4, which does not support class constants; when it sees code like that, it's expecting a static function call, which it *does* support:

```
Class::static_function()
```

However, in the case of your code, the `Zend_Oauth` class has a `const REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER`, a PHP 5-only feature, which is accessed like so:

```
Zend_Oauth::REQUEST_SCHEME_HEADER
```

This is why Zend Framework requires PHP 5. If you intend to use it, yes you'll need to contact your hosting provider to see if they offer PHP 5 as an option or something.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running PHP4.

Most likely your server has both php5 and php4 installed, but it defaults to php4. Contact your server provider.